# PHP requirement error when installing spatie-media-library-pro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm trying to install spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro:^2.0.0 but hitting the error "- spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro 2.0.0 requires php ^8.0 which does not match your installed version 7.4.14."

My IDE is phpstorm which is using PHP 8.1.
My composer.json requires php 8.1

I think I can work around the problem by using "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs" but I'd prefer to understand why I'm hitting the problem.
All thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to remove vendor folder and run compose install?

Comment: @gguney I tried that, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your development environment.

## Laravel Homestead

If you're using [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead#php-versions), you can change PHP version in different ways:

1. Running `php81`. This will change the default CLI version for all applications installed in the Virtual Machine
2. Adding the version to `Homestead.yml`

   ```
   sites:
   - map: your-site.test
     to: /home/vagrant/your-site/public
     php: "8.1"
   ```

## Laravel Sail

If you're using [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#sail-php-versions), you should update the build definition of the your-site.test container in your application's docker-compose.yml file:

```
# PHP 8.1
context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
```

## Custom setup

In any other case, it will depend on how your local env is setup. Try running `php -v` to figure out what version the CLI is using.